# Getting data from QPointF in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I am pushing plotted data from a chart in an array, the data at the end looks like this:

```
qml: [QPointF(0, 0.5),QPointF(0, 0.25),QPointF(0, 0.61),QPointF(0, 1),QPointF(0, 0.1),QPointF(0, 0.67),QPointF(0, 0.12)]
```

How to access the y point in this case? I want to get the max and min for all points.

Comment: `myArray[index].y`? It's unclear from your question...

Comment: Should it work in QML! it is not working for me, undefined function!

Comment: Yep, it _should_ work in qml. You mentioned an array and data resembling an array of QPoints, so you should be able to access each point individually by indexing the array (and then following Amfasis's answer). (Ps, `myArray`, and `index` were just placeholders.)

Comment: What kind of array do you send ?, you can show the C++ code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `.x` and `.y`

example:

```
property var mypoint : <from C++ or anywhere>
property real myX : mypoint.x
property real myY : mypoint.y
```